# get_query_var returns wrong default value

Tags: order, query-variable

I want to make my custom terms to be sortable by users. I've created different links to let the user decide how they want to sort it.

```
<a href="?orderby=name&order=asc" data-target="#">Name ascending</a>
<a href="?orderby=name&order=desc" data-target="#">Name descending</a>

<?php
$orderby = get_query_var('orderby', 'name');
$order = get_query_var('order', 'ASC');

echo $orderby . " : " . $order;  
$args = [
    'number' => $tpp, // Amount of terms to return
    'offset' => $offset, // The amount to offset the list by for pagination
    'orderby' => $orderby,
    'order' => $order
 ];
 $actors = get_terms( 'myTaxonomy', $args );
```

It works properly if the query vars are set. But if no query var is provided, I always get `DESC`.

As the default value for `$order` although I defined `ASC` as default.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default value of `get_query_var( $var, $default )` is only returned if the query variable `$var` isn't available in the global `$wp_query` object.

The `order` query variable actually falls back to the `DESC` value [here](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/87ad9e31abe80de94c9f229a82337530bf37cf91/wp-includes/class-wp-query.php#L2151):

```
if ( ! isset( $q['order'] ) ) {
    $q['order'] = $rand ? '' : 'DESC';
} ...
```

within `WP_Query::get_posts()`, so that's why it's used instead of your default value.

Be careful when applying native public query variables, to secondary queries, because they can also change the main query result.